# How to use Youtube feed in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a requirement to use a youtube URL, say example http://www.youtube.com/user/nokia/feed
in my windows phone 7 application. I want to download the feed url and list it accordingly. Can some one help me with the starter?

Answer (score 0):

Google has an [API for YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api) that will allow you to easily perform this task from a Windows Phone device. Per Google's site:

About the Google Data API

The Data API allows a program to perform many of the operations available on the YouTube website. It is possible to search for videos, retrieve standard feeds, and see related content. A program can also authenticate as a user to upload videos, modify user playlists, and more.

The Data API is primarily for developers who are programming in server-side languages. It's useful for sites or applications that want to have a deep integration with YouTube, such as an app that captures video and lets users upload that video directly to YouTube. The Data API gives you programmatic access to YouTube video and user information, enabling you to personalize your application with users' existing information and to perform actions, like rating or commenting on videos, on their behalf.

The Developer's Guide *explains* how the Data API works at the basic level using XML and HTTP. This guide details the requests and responses that the YouTube API servers expect and return. The Reference Guide provides more detail about the structure of these requests and responses. The reference guide defines the API's feed types, HTTP request parameters, HTTP response codes, and XML elements. You may also want to read about the Google Data Protocol and the Atom Publishing Protocol, which are the standards upon which the Data API is built.

To make working with the API easier, we have a number of client libraries that abstract the API into a language-specific object model. These client libraries are open-source and can be used and modified under the Apache License 2.0. There are **Developer's Guides** for **Java**, **.NET**, **PHP**, and **Python** as well as **sample code**.

Explore this page [YouTube API v2.0 - Understanding Feeds and Entries](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_understanding_video_feeds) which states:

When you retrieve a video feed or list of search results, YouTube returns an Atom feed that contains one  tag for each video in the result set. The root XML tag in the response will be the  tag. In addition to the information about the individual videos in the result set, the feed will also contain the total number of results in the list, the index of the first item in the list, the number of items in the list and other metadata about the feed.

The following XML shows the format of a YouTube Data API response containing a video feed:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/'
    xmlns:gml='http://www.opengis.net/gml'
    xmlns:georss='http://www.georss.org/georss'
    xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'
    xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'
    xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'
    xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
    gd:etag='W/&quot;CE4EQH47eCp7ImA9WxRQGEQ.&quot;'>
  <id>tag:youtube,2008:standardfeed:us:top_rated</id>
  <updated>2008-07-18T05:00:49.000-07:00</updated>
  <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
    term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video'/>
  <title>Top Rated</title>
  <logo>http://www.youtube.com/img/pic_youtubelogo_123x63.gif</logo>
  <link rel='alternate' type='text/html'
    href='https://www.youtube.com/browse?s=tr'/>
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed'
    type='application/atom+xml'
    href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?v=2'/>
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch'
    type='application/atom+xml'
    href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated/batch?v=2'/>
  <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml'
    href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?...'/>
  <link rel='service' type='application/atomsvc+xml'
    href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?...'/>
  <link rel='next' type='application/atom+xml'
    href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?...'/>
  <author>
    <name>YouTube</name>
    <uri>http://www.youtube.com/</uri>
  </author>
  <generator version='2.0'
    uri='http://gdata.youtube.com/'>YouTube data API</generator>
  <openSearch:totalResults>100</openSearch:totalResults>
  <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
  <openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
  <entry gd:etag='W/&quot;C0AMRn47eCp7ImA9WxRQGUw.&quot;'>
    <id>tag:youtube,2008:video:ZTUVgYoeN_b</id>
    <published>2008-07-05T19:56:35.000-07:00</published>
    <updated>2008-07-18T07:21:59.000-07:00</updated>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
      term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat'
      term='Shopping'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat'
      term='parkas'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'
      term='People' label='People'/>
    <title>Shopping for Coats</title>
    <content type='application/x-shockwave-flash'
      src='http://www.youtube.com/v/ZTUVgYoeN_b?f=gdata_standard...'/>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html'
      href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTUVgYoeN_b'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.responses'
      type='application/atom+xml'
      href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/responses?v=2'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.ratings'
      type='application/atom+xml'
      href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/ratings?v=2'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.complaints'
      type='application/atom+xml'
      href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/complaints?v=2'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related'
      type='application/atom+xml'
      href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/related?v=2'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile'
      type='text/html' href='https://m.youtube.com/details?v=ZTUVgYoeN_b'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#uploader'
      type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw?v=2'/>
    <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml'
      href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated/v/ZTUVgYoeN_b?v=2'/>
    <author>
      <name>GoogleDevelopers</name>
      <uri>https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers</uri>
      <yt:userId>_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw<</yt:userId>
    </author>
    <yt:accessControl action='comment' permission='allowed'/>
    <yt:accessControl action='commentVote' permission='allowed'/>
    <yt:accessControl action='videoRespond' permission='moderated'/>
    <yt:accessControl action='rate' permission='allowed'/>
    <yt:accessControl action='embed' permission='allowed'/>
    <yt:accessControl action='list' permission='allowed'/>
    <yt:accessControl action='autoPlay' permission='allowed'/>
    <yt:accessControl action='syndicate' permission='allowed'/>
    <gd:comments>
      <gd:feedLink href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/comments'
        countHint='9416'/>
    </gd:comments>
    <georss:where>
      <gml:Point>
        <gml:pos>21.37124437061831 -157.87353515625</gml:pos>
      </gml:Point>
    </georss:where>
    <yt:hd/>
    <media:group>
      <media:category label='People'
        scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>People
      </media:category>
      <media:content 
        url='http://www.youtube.com/v/ZTUVgYoeN_b?f=gdata_standard...'
        type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video'
        isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='215' yt:format='5'/>
      <media:content
        url='rtsp://rtsp2.youtube.com/ChoLENy73bIAEQ1kgGDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp'
        type='video/3gpp' medium='video'
        expression='full' duration='215' yt:format='1'/>
      <media:content
        url='rtsp://rtsp2.youtube.com/ChoLENy73bIDRQ1kgGDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp'
        type='video/3gpp' medium='video'
        expression='full' duration='215' yt:format='6'/>
      <media:credit role='uploader' scheme='urn:youtube'
          yt:display='GoogleDevelopers'>GoogleDevelopers</media:credit>
      <media:description type='plain'>
        What could make for more exciting video?
      </media:description>
      <media:keywords>Shopping, parkas</media:keywords>
      <media:license type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/t/terms'>youtube</media:license>
      <media:player url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTUVgYoeN_b'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/ZTUVgYoeN_b/2.jpg'
        height='90' width='120' time='00:00:03.500'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/ZTUVgYoeN_b/1.jpg'
        height='90' width='120' time='00:00:01.750'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/ZTUVgYoeN_b/3.jpg'
        height='90' width='120' time='00:00:05.250'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/ZTUVgYoeN_b/0.jpg'
        height='360' width='480' time='00:00:03.500'/>
      <media:title type='plain'>Shopping for Coats</media:title>
      <yt:aspectRatio>widescreen</yt:aspectRatio>
      <yt:duration seconds='79'/>
      <yt:uploaded>2008-07-05T19:56:35.000-07:00</yt:uploaded>
      <yt:uploaderId>UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw</yt:uploaderId>
      <yt:videoid>ZTUVgYoeN_b</yt:videoid>
    </media:group>
    <gd:rating min='1' max='5' numRaters='14763' average='4.93'/>
    <yt:recorded>2008-07-04</yt:recorded>
    <yt:statistics viewCount='383290' favoriteCount='7022'/>
    <yt:rating numDislikes='19257' numLikes='106000'/>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

As an alternative, this could be accomplished with the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) by parsing out the DOM, but you should explore the above solution before jumping off the cliff into DOM parsing and/or using this in conjunction with the Google YouTube API.

Source: [Google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api)